# Regex for htaccess to match pattern unless directory exists

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using regex in a htaccess file to catch /[username] and re-direct this to a username page, for example, mywebsite.com/john will forward to mywebsite.com/username?u=john. This works, but I now want to exclude anything that matches a directory which exists. So, if someone goes to mywebsite.com/sign-up, this is EXCLUDED for the re-direction, because that directory (/sign-up) exists. Is that possible, and is it normal practice? Thank you.

Edit: Ideally I don't want to have to exclude every existing directory manually. I'd like it to be automatic for all existing directories.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rewrite condition before it.  !-f means not an existing file, !-d means not an existing directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ username?u=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried that, and it works for some cases but not all. For example, If I append '/log-in' then the re-direction correctly doesn't happen, but if I append '/css' then the direction DOES happen even though my css directory does exist. Any thoughts?